# Excel VBA to Word Doc - Changing font styles within a sentence/paragraph

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

My goal is to write a sentence/paragraph with the ability to change font styles within the same sentence/paragraph. This is being done in **Excel VBA** and outputs in a word document (I'm sure you can tell).

Example: "Please see **Table 1**. *Note Table 1 is assumed.*"

With the code below it seems to set the whole sentence to the last wdStyleTypeCharacter that was called out.

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Set appWord = New Word.Application
appWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = appWord.Documents.Add

Set Normal = objDoc.Styles.Add(Name:="Normal", Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)
Set Bold = objDoc.Styles.Add(Name:="Bold", Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)
Set Italic = objDoc.Styles.Add(Name:="Italic", Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)

With objDoc

With .Styles(Normal)
.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
.Font.Size = 11
.Font.Italic = False
.Font.Bold = False
End With

With .Styles(Bold)
.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
.Font.Size = 11
.Font.Italic = False
.Font.Bold = True
End With

With .Styles(Italic)
.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
.Font.Size = 11
.Font.Italic = True
.Font.Bold = False
End With

.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
.Range.Style = .Styles(Normal)
.Content.InsertAfter "Please see "
.Range.Style = .Styles(Bold)
.Content.InsertAfter "Table 1"
.Range.Style = .Styles(Italic)
.Content.InsertAfter ".  Note Table 1 is assumed."
.Content.InsertParagraphAfter

End with

objDoc.Close savechanges:=wdSaveChanges
appWord.Quit
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If im not mistaken it's doing exactly what your code says.  Within your main`With` you're changing the style three different times and the last one is the Italic.  Try separting out your `With` into the three sentences/styles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why you have to you .selection the word.application but this solves my problem. If anyone could answer this that would be great just for my basic understanding (new to this).

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Set appWord = New Word.Application
appWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = appWord.Documents.Add

With appWord.Selection
.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
.Font.Size = 11
.TypeText Text:="Please see "
.Font.Bold = wdToggle
.TypeText Text:="Table 1"
.Font.Bold = wdToggle
.Font.Italic = wdToggle
.TypeText Text:=". Note Table 1 is assumed."
End With

objDoc.Close savechanges:=wdSaveChanges
appWord.Quit
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope this can help someone else in the future.